# SQL select query with form data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is an alternative to the following(PLEASE NOTE I AM NOT WORRIED ABOUT SECURITY RIGHT NOW)

```
$value = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '$value'";
```

So instead of having $value in apostrophes can we use it in the SQL statements without having to use the apostrophes and use and alternative?

Comment: This largely depends on the Client and Server software. e.g. PHP/MySQL is different than C#/SQL Server. You'll need to update your question with the appropriate tags

Comment: Usually, yes but just for numbers.

Comment: You should absolutely be worried about security now.  It will dictate decisions you make on how to query the database.  Ironically enough using prepared statements (something the provides great security benefits against SQL injection) would actually likely be a good answer to your question.  The point being that you shouldn't separate thinking about security from the rest of your design and implementation, unless you like to rewrite your code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use bind variables. Refer to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) for an example (that's an Oracle example, but other DB's should be similar).

Bind variables will also help your application performance with most databases, since the query plan can be reused if you are executing multiple queries of this type.

Since you updated your answer to indicate you were using MySQL, refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for an example of bind variables for that DB.